# I'm trying to make a scripts and this error comes up

Tags: python

it gives me this error and i all ready tried searching up common fixes and none of them work

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

````
def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.turn(UP)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.turn(DOWN)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.turn(LEFT)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.turn(RIGHT) ```
````

Comment: well, the indentation for the function you have shown is fine, (try pasting it into an empty file, it works) either it got fixed in pasting it into SO or the indentation issue is somewhere else in your module. Either way we can't really help you with what is currently provided.

Comment: It is most likely that the def is not indented the same amount as the method above it, as I assume it is inside a class.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error should show you in which line is problem and then you should check if this line has the same indentation as other lines. BTW: one `tab` looks like 4 `spaces` but for Python it is difference and sometimes it can makes problem. Some editors/IDEs has function to convert all tabs to spaces (or they can do it when you save file)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is mixing tabs and spaces. You have different indentations for the start of the function and the rest of the program.

Change your tabs to  4 space indentations, also to debug you can make your editor make tabs and spaces visible to see if you have a collision.

Answer (score 0):

You indented the block for the function twice. Try:

```
def handle_keys(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.turn(UP)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.turn(DOWN)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.turn(LEFT)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.turn(RIGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentations have to be the same. The first one (between `def handle_keys(self):` and `for event in pygame.event.get():`) has a different different indetantion than the other ones.

Comment: This isn't actually invalid, bad practice but not invalid.

Comment: I'm afraid that when he unindent, python won't understand he "left" the process.